# greatest common divisor via induction?

Tags: induction

could someone provide a nice explaination for the following problem. I´m repeating some old exercises and stuck with this one:

I have to prove via induction from $(n-1)$ to $n$ for all natural $n,m$ $\in$  $\mathbb{N_+}$ that relationship:
(greatest common divisor)gcd$(2^n-1,2^m-1)=2^{gcd(n,m)}-1$,

and I have to use the Euclidean algorithm.....

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Comment: thank you for the reference